# How to set up a pom.xml to process certain directories with Maven for Sonar?

Tags: php, maven, pom.xml, sonarqube

I have a directory structure something like this:

- base

  - **subdir1**
  - subdir2
  - subdir3

    - subsubdir1
    - **subsubdir2**
  - **subdir4**
  - unittests

How do I set up my pom.xml so that it only processes the folders in bold? If possible, I want them to all be processed in one `mvn sonar:sonar` call, and to show up as separate projects in Sonar. I tried looking at the documentation for the Project Object Model, but I found it to be overwhelming, and couldn't figure out how to set it up as I described. This is what my pom.xml, located in base, currently looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.foo.bar.baz</groupId>
        <artifactId>subsubdir2</artifactId>
        <name>MyProject</name>
        <version>1.0</version>

        <build>
                <sourceDirectory>subdir3/subsubdir2</sourceDirectory>
                <testSourceDirectory>unittests</testSourceDirectory>
        </build>

        <properties>
                <sonar.language>php</sonar.language>
                <sonar.phase>generate-sources</sonar.phase>
        </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the top level pom and use the [sonar.skippedModules or sonar.includedModules property](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Advanced+parameters) to set up the list of modules to build. This won't show each module as a separate project at the top level of sonar, but if you go into the project and select "modules", then you'll see each one listed, as if it were a separate project.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it's not working. I moved pom.xml out of base, set sourceDirectory to `base`, testSourceDirectory to `base/unittests`, and added this to the properties: `<sonar.includedModules>base,base/subdir1,base/subdir3/subsubdir2,base/subdir4</sonar.includedModules>`, and it says: Embedded error: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public void org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex.start()', instance 'org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex@15004dd, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
Can not find the root project from the list of Maven modules

Comment: Okay, in a maven project, each module, including the top level one (base in your example) needs to have a pom.xml in it. Do you have that? And the value that you give to sonar as the "module" to include or exclude should be the artifactId of the module, not the name of the directory it lives in.

Comment: Could you please give an example both of what the pom.xml in base, and the one in one of the modules should look like? Thanks!

Comment: If you use git, you can clone my testbed repo: `git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed.git tmp`. It's a multimodule Java project. The main thing to note is that the pom at the root level has a section named "modules", which names all the modules that come under that pom. That makes it so that when you build the root pom, all the modules get built, too.

Comment: @Aistina: you could also read about [inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) and [aggregation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) in Maven.